# Add a CSV column based on file name

Tags: python, csv

I have followings `CSV` files as input files in a directory:

```sh
USA_Chicago_data.csv
USA_Dallas_data.csv
```

Which has data like this:

```
Area          Population   No_of_houses
Brookfield    100000        20000
Springdale    50000         10000
```

I want to add a column in the beginning of the file with city name based on the file name.

Sample output for `USA_Chicago_data.csv`:

```
City     Area          Population   No_of_houses
Chicago  Brookfield    100000        20000
Chicago  Springdale    50000         10000
```

It should have condition to read the file name and extract the city from it and add it in first column.

I am trying below script:

```py
with open(file, 'r') as csvinput:
  if ("Chicago" in file):
    with open('file'+_output.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        for row in csv.reader(csvinput):
            writer.writerow(row + ['City'])
```

But it is running into error. What could be the solution? I want to achieve this without using pandas.

Comment: If that is exactly your code, you are missing a `'` in `+_output.csv'`.

Comment: Please show the full error you are getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.  You have a syntax error in your second "open" statement, because of a quote mixup.

```
# Extract the city:
city = file.split('_')[1]

with open(file,'r') as csvinput, open(f'USA_{city}_data_output.csv','w') as cvsoutput:
    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
    for row in csv.reader(csvinput):
        if row[0] == 'Area':
            row.insert( 0, 'City')
        else:
            row.insert( 0, city )
        writer.writerow(row)
```

### Followup

To overwrite the original file, you'd need:

```
# Extract the city:
city = file.split('_')[1]
newfile = f'USA_{city}_data_output.csv'

with open(file,'r') as csvinput, open(newfile,'w') as cvsoutput:
    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
    for row in csv.reader(csvinput):
        if row[0] == 'Area':
            row.insert( 0, 'City')
        else:
            row.insert( 0, city )
        writer.writerow(row)

os.remove( file )
os.rename( newfile, file )
```

Comment: That will not work for city names with more than one word. `New_Hampshire`, for example.

Comment: You are correct.  An approach like `file.find('_data')` would be more robust.  But since we don't know how the OP would want that to be presented in the file, I'm going to leave that as an "exercise for the reader".

Comment: Something like `re.split('USA_(.*)_data.csv', file)[1].replace('_', ' ')` will do, perhaps.

Comment: Or even better: `city = re.sub('USA_(.*)_data.csv', r'\1', file).replace('_', ' ')`.

Comment: And here is another idea: `city = ' '.join(_ for _ in file.split('_') if _ not in ('USA', 'data.csv'))`.

Comment: Or even just `city = ' '.join( file.split('_')[1:-1] )`.

Comment: Condition to check if row[0] == 'Area' is not working. It is printing the city name in column name also.

Comment: That means your CSV file doesn't actually say what you said it does.  Go LOOK at the header line.  What, EXACTLY, does it say?  Does it start with the word "Area", spelled and capitalized exactly that way?

Comment: How do I write the below sentence if I want to keep the output name same as input? open(f'USA_{city}_data_output.csv','w') as cvsoutput

Comment: You can't write to a file you're reading from.  You will have to delete the old and rename it after you're done.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for